# Cannot use Application.Evaluate() for CUBEVALUE function

Tags: vba, excel, powerpivot

Dear MS Excel wizards =)

Recently I'm developing a `UserForm` for Budget file, to bring all basic controls to one place and ease the life of users. My initial idea was calculating all primary values (starting num of Students, finishing num of Students...) in this form and feed to Budget file formulas as values. For some calculations, I have to address `ThisWorkbookDataModel`, therefore I was planning to use `Application.Evaluate()`

Yet it fails with case like this:

```
m1 = Application.Evaluate("=CUBEVALUE(""ThisWorkbookDataModel"",CUBEMEMBER(""ThisWorkbookDataModel"",{""[DimDate].[1.Year].&[" & mYear & "]"",""[DimDate].[3.MonthCalendarTrue].&[" & mMonth & "]""}),CUBEMEMBER(""ThisWorkbookDataModel"",""[Measures].[mQofStudents]""),CUBEMEMBER(""ThisWorkbookDataModel"",{""[DimCampus].[Burleigh]""}))")
```

As a workaround, I evaluate this formula on the worksheet first:

```
Range("AvgStudStartValBH").Formula = "=CUBEVALUE(""ThisWorkbookDataModel"",CUBEMEMBER(""ThisWorkbookDataModel"",{""[DimDate].[1.Year].&[" & mYear & "]"",""[DimDate].[3.MonthCalendarTrue].&[" & mMonth & "]""}),CUBEMEMBER(""ThisWorkbookDataModel"",""[Measures].[mQofStudents]""),CUBEMEMBER(""ThisWorkbookDataModel"",{""[DimCampus].[Burleigh]""}))"
```

Yet this really creates inconveniences in refreshing of the result in `UserForm`.

What I found while debugging this `Application.Evaluate()` issue is that if I cut away last `CUBEMEMBER()`, it works! So maybe `Application.Evaluate()` has a limit in symbols?
If so, is there any other workaround except pasting this into Excel worksheet to evaluate there before getting this to the form?

Comment: You may try to use named formula instead of evaluating in the worksheet cell.

Comment: are you trying to add an array formula?

Comment: Or you might be right on your assumption that there is a limit in `Application.Evaluate` function in terms of number of characters. I will try to check.

Comment: Ok, confirmed it. [`Application.Evaluate` is limited to 255 characters only](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-evaluate-method-excel).

Comment: L42, thanks for your investigation! Now I will know for sure...